# WSL2 unable to connect to IP address (not DNS) on Cisco Anyconnect VPN

Tags: vpn, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, cisco-vpn-client, cisco-anyconnect

Preface: This is not a DNS issue.  I am working with explicit IP addresses here and cannot make connections.  There are a lot of questions for my same situation but involving DNS resolution.  I have not gotten to that point - still manual IP addresses not working for me.

On a corporate VPN with the Cisco anyconnect client with limited admin capabilities on Windows 10.  No common linux tools will connect to known IP addresses from my WSL2 (the podman default one).  telnet, curl, wget, etc.  All timeout.  Including trying to hit the local host windows machine at the WSL's virtual adapter address.

As soon as I disconnect from the VPN, it works.

Reconnect, doesn't work again.

Have tried starting the WSL before or after connecting to the VPN with no change.

I would not think it's firewall related since it works fine off of the VPN?

Edit: I can also hit the IP address of the WSL instance from the windows host only when off the VPN.

Comment: is your VPN client configured to allow reverse tunneling? do both systems have routes pointing back and forth between them?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that DNS is still used (to some degree) even if you use an IP address to contact a machine. Your issue is the VPN configuration.  So you must contact whomever is responsible for your corporate VPN to help diagnose what setting might be blocking the connection.